# spring reactive retry with exponential backoff conditionally

Tags: spring, reactive, exponential-backoff

Using spring reactive WebClient, I consume an API and in case of response with 500 status I need to retry with exponential backoff. But in Mono class, I don't see any retryBackoff with Predicate as input parameter.

This is the kind of function I search for:

```
public final Mono<T> retryBackoff(Predicate<? super Throwable> retryMatcher, long numRetries, Duration firstBackoff)
```

Right now my implementation is as following (I don't have retry with backOff mechanism):

```
client.sendRequest()
    .retry(e -> ((RestClientException) e).getStatus() == 500)
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to have a look at the `reactor-extra` module in the [reactor-addons](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons) project. In Maven you can do:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-extra</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And then use it like this:

```java
client.post()
    .syncBody("test")
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .retryWhen(Retry.onlyIf(ctx -> ctx.exception() instanceof RestClientException)
                    .exponentialBackoff(firstBackoff, maxBackoff)
                    .retryMax(maxRetries))
```

Answer (score 4):

`Retry.onlyIf` is now deprecated/removed.

If anyone is interested in the up-to-date solution:

```java
client.post()
      .syncBody("test")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(String.class)
      .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(maxRetries, minBackoff).filter(ctx -> {
          return ctx.exception() instanceof RestClientException && ctx.exception().statusCode == 500; 
      }))
```

It's worth mentioning that `retryWhen` wraps the source exception into the `RetryExhaustedException`. If you want to 'restore' the source exception you can use the `reactor.core.Exceptions` util:

```java
.onErrorResume(throwable -> {
    if (Exceptions.isRetryExhausted(throwable)) {
        throwable = throwable.getCause();
    }
    return Mono.error(throwable);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what spring version you are using, in 2.1.4 I have this:

```
client.post()
    .syncBody("test")
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .retryBackoff(numretries, firstBackoff, maxBackoff, jitterFactor);
```

... so that's exactly what you want, right?

Comment: He want's to retry only on error 500, not 400, not 501...only 500.

Comment: `retryBackoff` was removed in Reactor 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying it with Kotlin Coroutines + Spring WebFlux:

It seems the following is not working:

```kotlin
suspend fun ClientResponse.asResponse(): ServerResponse =
    status(statusCode())
        .headers { headerConsumer -> headerConsumer.addAll(headers().asHttpHeaders()) }
        .body(bodyToMono(DataBuffer::class.java), DataBuffer::class.java)
        .retryWhen { 
            Retry.onlyIf { ctx: RetryContext<Throwable> -> (ctx.exception() as? WebClientResponseException)?.statusCode in retryableErrorCodes }
                .exponentialBackoff(ofSeconds(1), ofSeconds(5))
                .retryMax(3)
                .doOnRetry { log.error("Retry for {}", it.exception()) }
        )
        .awaitSingle()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AtomicInteger errorCount = new AtomicInteger();
Flux<String> flux =
Flux.<String>error(new IllegalStateException("boom"))
        .doOnError(e -> { 
            errorCount.incrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(e + " at " + LocalTime.now());
        })
        .retryWhen(Retry
                .backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(100)).jitter(0d) 
                .doAfterRetry(rs -> System.out.println("retried at " + LocalTime.now() + ", attempt " + rs.totalRetries())) 
                .onRetryExhaustedThrow((spec, rs) -> rs.failure()) 
        );
```

We will log the time of errors emitted by the source and count them.

We configure an exponential backoff retry with at most 3 attempts and no jitter.

We also log the time at which the retry happens, and the retry attempt number (starting from 0).

By default, an Exceptions.retryExhausted exception would be thrown, with the last failure() as a cause. Here we customize that to directly emit the cause as onError.